# telegram desktop doesn't auto download pictures

Tags: windows-10, file-download, telegram-messenger

Unfortunately Telegram Desktop doesn´t download pictures even if I enable all options as told below.

[How to disable telegram desktop auto media download feature](https://superuser.com/questions/1035956/how-to-disable-telegram-desktop-auto-media-download-feature)

Does anybody know help?

Answer (score 3):

Actually telegram desktop (up to 1.54) doesn’t work as you (and I) expect. The auto download media settings just control which kind media are automatically downloaded from telegram servers in order to avoid exceeding data plan limits. That makes sense for mobile apps but definitely less relevant for the desktop one. What confuses people in the case of the Win desktop application is videos are automatically saved in the folder Download\Telegram Desktop\ and they expect to find the pictures at the same location whereas the pictures are cryptically saved in the cache folder of the telegram installation directory. Why telegram makes a decrypted copy of videos in download folder and not for the pictures? I don’t know.